# Excel-Pivot Expanded fields

Tags: excel

How can I make the Pivot table data in Expanded form automatically? I dont want the user to click on the + icon to expand the field

[image]

Comment: do you want to remove the expand icons?

Comment: If removing the + expand button doesnt mess with the data, then yes. Else, we can keep the expand icon but in expanded form